# How to import `Facebook-iOS-SDK` into bridging header?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I need to import into `Project-Bridging-Header.h` the following library from cocoapods: `Facebook-iOS-SDK`.

but when I put:

```
@import Facebook-iOS-SDK;
```

then I get error:

> Module 'Facebook' not found.

Why?

Comment: Do you read this info https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put: `@import FacebookSDK;`.